# Como crear un WorkManager para activar una alarma?

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito crear una alarma estaba utilizando AlarmManager y todo iba bien pero cuando reinicio el teléfono esta se activa a los minutos de encenderlo y no acata las fechas y horas establecidas para que esta suene.
Me sugirieron crear un WorkManager ya lo implemente pero no se como hacer que este se me active (ejemplo: todos los lunes a las 8:30 am).
Espero me puedan ayudar. 
Mil Gracias

```
private void startWork(){

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();


    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkTecno.class, 8, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConstraints(constraints).build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(getContext()).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);

}
```

Comment: Usando AlarmManager puedes realizarlo sin problema, de hecho ese es el objetivo de la clase.

Comment: Pero con el alarmmanager cuando reinicio el telefono se activa inmediatamente y no se activa cuando se debe activar.